# Is it Possible to recover from a temporal table?

Tags: sql, db2

is it Possible to recover from a temporal table?

I defined 2 tables like this:

```
create table lib.x(
  "ID" INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( 
       START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 
       NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE 
       NO CYCLE NO ORDER 
       CACHE 20 
    ),
    char char(1),
    row_start TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW BEGIN IMPLICITLY hidden,
    row_end TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END IMPLICITLY hidden,
    row_id TIMESTAMP(12) GENERATED ALWAYS AS TRANSACTION START ID IMPLICITLY hidden,
    PERIOD SYSTEM_TIME(row_start, row_end)
);

create table lib.x_history like lib.x;


alter TABLE lib.x
ADD VERSIONING USE HISTORY TABLE lib.x_history;
```

then I did this:

```
insert into lib.x(char) values('a'), ('b'), ('c');
delete from lib.x where id = 2;
```

Is it possible to restore the char 'b' with the ID 2?

Comment: I recommend against using identity columns with temporal tables - the result can be surprising as internal functions handle the historization. Use sequences is my recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. It is not a system restore, but of course you can query the old state and use it to insert into the regular table. See the section "[Querying system-period temporal data](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0058930.html)" in the Db2 docs.

You would first construct a query to search AS OF. Later, you could use it as input to an insert statement. Thus, you restore the value, but it is treated as deleting the value and inserting it as new.

Comment: @iiSiggi if you are working with db2 for i (as400) you can keep that id using `overriding system value` in your `ÌNSERT` statement